# Proof of an inequality involving factorials

Tags: inequality, factorial

How can the following inequality be proven?
$$\left(n!\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}\left((n+1)!\right)^{-\frac{1}{n+1}}\gt\dfrac{n}{n+1}$$
I know this is a result obtained in 1964, but I don't know how to prove it or where to find the proof. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you clear fractions, raise both sides to the power $n(n+1)$, and cancel common factors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the sketch of the proof.
$$
(n!)^{n+1}((n+1)!)^{-n}\gt \frac{n^{n^2+n}}{(n+1)^{n^2+n}},\\
\frac{n!}{(n+1)^n}\gt \frac{n^{n(n+1)}}{(n+1)^{n(n+1)}},\\
n!\gt \frac{n^{n(n+1)}}{(n+1)^{n^2}},\\
$$
Last inequality can be proved using induction and $$
\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \lt \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n+1}. 
$$